# fetch undefined in guild.roles

Tags: discord.js, roles

Hello I am trying to write a discordbot that syncs a role A on members in guild A to guildB
those Roles are defined by ID
the problem i have is that `var users1 = guild1.roles.fetch(args[2]).members; //guild1role` throws

```
(node:54852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
at SyncRole.run (D:\git\purgebot\Commands\General\syncrole.js:49:37)
at Message.run (D:\git\purgebot\Events\message.js:49:13)
at Luna.<anonymous> (D:\git\purgebot\Luna.js:92:83)
at Luna.emit (events.js:314:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\git\purgebot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

Here is the source code of the part that syncs the roles (line 1 = line 37)

```
const client = this.client;

if(message.member.guild.me.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {

    var guild1 = client.guilds.fetch(args[0]); //guildid1
    var guild2 = client.guilds.fetch(args[1]); //guildid1

    var users1 = guild1.roles.fetch(args[2]).members; //guild1role
    var users2 = guild2.roles.fetch(args[3]).members; //guild2role

    users2.members.forEach(user => {
        user.remove(args[3]).catch(console.error);
        message.channel.send("removed role " + args[3] + " for " + user.id);
    })

    users1.members.forEach(user =>{
        guild2.members.forEach(user2 => {
            if(user.id == user2.id) {
                user2.addRole(args[3]);
                message.channel.send("added role " + args[3] + " for " + user.id);
            }
        })
    })

    message.channel.send("roles synced");
} else {
    message.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/6cpffM4.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a `Promise`, which must be resolved before you can use the `Guild` object. So does [`RoleManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
// using `Promise.prototype.then()`

client.guilds.fetch(args[0]).then((guildid1) => {
 client.guilds.fetch(args[1]).then((guildid2) => {
  let users1, users2;
  guild1.roles.fetch(args[2]).then((role) => (users1 = role.members));
  guild2.roles.fetch(args[3]).then((role) => (users2 = role.members));
  // code...
 });
});

// using `async/await`
// **make sure your function is `async`**

const guild1 = await client.guilds.fetch(args[0]);
const guild2 = await client.guilds.fetch(args[1]);

const users1 = (await guild1.roles.fetch(args[2])).members;
const users2 = (await guild2.roles.fetch(args[3])).members;
```